# How to filter the retrieved items using a pnp-js-core REST call to a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, typescript, pnp-js-core

As I am new to Sharepoint framework , I am trying to filter the retrieved list items from sharepoint list.
Please find below code:

```
pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get().then(function(res){  
 
var userEmail = res.Email;
  });
     
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeMaster').items.select("EmployeeID,Title,Designation,Email").filter("Email eq " + userEmail + "'").get().then(function(results){
      
var empID = results[0].EmployeeID;});
```

Above code is giving me an error of undefined.
Please suggest an workaround...

Comment: What is the column type of Email ? Is it a single line of text or you are trying to filter on Email of Person or Group column ?

Comment: it is Single line of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the code for this error(SitePages).
[image]

If it is caused by this error, you can find the solution here.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Using-sp-pnp-js-in-SharePoint-Framework

**Updated code:**

```
pnp.sp.web.currentUser.get().then(function(res){  
 
var userEmail = res.Email;
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('EmployeeMaster').items.select("EmployeeID,Title,Designation,Email").filter("Email eq '" + userEmail + "'").get().then(function(results){
      
var empID = results[0].EmployeeID;});
  });
```

js asynchronous request order solution for your reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: _api/web/lists/getByTitle('EmployeeMaster')/items?...This is the api which I am getting..

Comment: Which variable does the error message say is undefined?

Comment: when I pass a static email i.e. filter("Email eq 'abc@gmail.com'")....then it works fine but on passing the variable it is not working

Comment: Check the update.All are asynchronous requests, the order issue is particularly important.

Comment: Thanks...Now it's working fine

Comment: You could mark my reply as answer and vote it,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a single quote in your filter expression.

```
filter("Email eq " + userEmail + "'")
```

should be

```
filter("Email eq '" + userEmail + "'")
```

Comment: I have tried this as well..it is not working